# A procedure supposedly does not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, plpgsql

I'm trying to make a PostgreSQL system that simulate transfers between 5 banks. But I have a problem that I really do not manage to understand. PostgreSQL seems to not understand the types of my data (that seem however clear...). Here is my code :

```
--The two following commands could be grouped but, for lisibility, are not
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bank1_accounts, bank2_accounts, bank3_accounts, bank4_accounts,
bank5_accounts, clients, transfer_logs, end_of_day_transfers;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients
(
    name varchar PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transfer_logs
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    bank_from integer,
    bank_to integer,
    client_name varchar, --is not a foreign key because if the client
                         --is not referenced, then an error would occur
    amount float,
    success bool
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank1_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank2_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank3_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank4_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank5_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE end_of_day_transfers
(
    id serial,
    bank_from integer,
    bank_to integer,
    client_name varchar,
    amount float
);


INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('Client 1');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('Client 2');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('Client 3');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('Client 4');

INSERT INTO bank1_accounts VALUES (8, 2000, 'Client 2');
INSERT INTO bank1_accounts VALUES (12, 650, 'Client 1');
INSERT INTO bank2_accounts VALUES (2, 300, 'Client 3');
INSERT INTO bank3_accounts VALUES (2, 300, 'Client 4');

DO $$
BEGIN
PREPARE bank1_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank1_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DEALLOCATE bank1_add_amount;
    PREPARE bank1_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank1_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
BEGIN
PREPARE bank2_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank2_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DEALLOCATE bank2_add_amount;
    PREPARE bank2_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank2_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
BEGIN
PREPARE bank3_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank3_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DEALLOCATE bank3_add_amount;
    PREPARE bank3_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank3_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
BEGIN
PREPARE bank4_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank4_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DEALLOCATE bank4_add_amount;
    PREPARE bank4_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank4_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO $$
BEGIN
PREPARE bank5_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank5_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DEALLOCATE bank5_add_amount;
    PREPARE bank5_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank5_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_amount(bank integer, client_name varchar, amount float)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF bank = 1 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT client FROM bank1_accounts WHERE client=client_name) THEN
        RAISE DIVISION_BY_ZERO;
    END IF;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CALL bank%s_add_amount(%L, %s)', bank, client_name, amount);
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transfer_amount(bank_from integer, bank_to integer, client_name varchar, amount float)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CALL add_amount(%s, %L, %s)', bank_from, client_name, -amount);
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CALL add_amount(%s, %L, %s)', bank_to, client_name, amount);
    INSERT INTO transfer_logs (bank_from, bank_to, client_name, amount, success) VALUES (bank_from, bank_to, client_name, amount, TRUE);
    --EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --  INSERT INTO transfer_logs (bank_from, bank_to, client_name, amount, success) VALUES (bank_from, bank_to, client_name, amount, FALSE);
END $$;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE perform_end_of_day()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    ROW record;
BEGIN
    FOR ROW IN SELECT * FROM end_of_day_transfers
        LOOP CALL transfer_amount(ROW.bank_from, ROW.bank_to, ROW.client_name, ROW.amount);
    END LOOP;
END $$;

INSERT INTO end_of_day_transfers (bank_from, bank_to, client_name, amount) VALUES (1, 2, 'Client 1', 50);
CALL perform_end_of_day();
SELECT * FROM transfer_logs;
```

This is my error message (sorry, it is in french but you can use an online translator) :

```
ERROR: ERREUR:  la procédure bank1_add_amount(character varying, double precision) n'existe pas
LINE 1: CALL bank1_add_amount('Client 1'::varchar, -50::float)
             ^
HINT:  Aucune procédure ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous pourriez avoir besoin d'ajouter des conversions de type explicites.
QUERY:  CALL bank1_add_amount('Client 1'::varchar, -50::float)
CONTEXT:  fonction PL/pgSQL add_amount(integer,character varying,double precision), ligne 6 à EXECUTE
instruction SQL « CALL add_amount(1, 'Client 1', -50) »
fonction PL/pgSQL transfer_amount(integer,integer,character varying,double precision), ligne 3 à EXECUTE
instruction SQL « CALL transfer_amount(ROW.bank_from, ROW.bank_to, ROW.client_name, ROW.amount) »
fonction PL/pgSQL perform_end_of_day(), ligne 6 à CALL


SQL state: 42883
```

I tried to remove the following line and it removed the error : `EXECUTE FORMAT('CALL bank%s_add_amount(%L, %s)', bank, client_name, amount);`
However, this line is necesary for my program ...

Can you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Add the complete error message to your question text. 2) My guess is you are going to have explicitly cast the non-varchar values e.g. `CALL add_amount(%s::integer, %L, %s::float)`

Comment: Thank you but I tried and it did not function. Also, I will add the complete error message but it is in french.

Comment: bank1_accounts, bank2_accounts, etc. smells like a bad data model. You shouldn't create different tables for different content for the same type of records. With a proper 3NF data model, your SQL logic also becomes much easier

Comment: I know but it is a homework and I have to create "bank1_accounts", ... to use "PREPARE", "FORMAT" and "EXECUTE"...

Comment: The error is `CALL bank1_add_amount('Customer 1'::varchar, -50::float) ERROR: procedure bank1_add_amount(character varying, double precision) does not exist` and that is correct.  `PREPARE bank1_add_amount(varchar, float)` does not create a procedure it just prepares a query. Not sure how you are going  to get at it from inside the `DO` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a single typo in line 174:

```sql
EXECUTE FORMAT('CALL bank%s_add_amount(%L, %s)', bank, client_name, amount);
```

Your `bankN_add_amount`s are prepared statements, not procedures, so you run them using [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) rather than `CALL`. Due to collision between [PL/pgSQL's dynamic command `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and [plain SQL `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html), you need to combine both:

```sql
EXECUTE FORMAT('EXECUTE bank%s_add_amount(%L, %s)', bank, client_name, amount);
```

Once you correct that, the exception will be gone: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dB50vlLx).

---

[Remarks](https://dbfiddle.uk/ERmMHVId): You can use procedural [subblocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) to shorten your `DEALLOCATE IF EXISTS` construct:

```sql
DO $f$
BEGIN
   BEGIN DEALLOCATE bank1_add_amount;
         EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; 
   END;
   PREPARE bank1_add_amount(varchar, float) AS
    UPDATE bank1_accounts
    SET balance = balance + $2
    WHERE client = $1;
END $f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You also don't need to specify `LANGUAGE plpgsql` for [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html): that's the default:

> *`lang_name`*
> The name of the procedural language the code is written in. If omitted, the default is `plpgsql`.

If your `bankN_accounts` tables are identical, you can merge them and instead of having to create one for each bank (plus all the prepared statements), add a column that indicates the bank:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS banks
(   id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank_accounts
(   id int PRIMARY KEY,
    bank_id int references banks(id) on update cascade,
    balance float,
    client varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);
```

The way you set things up, you're only allowing for self-transfers between banks: you can specify `bank_from` and `bank_to`, but you assume the same client in both banks. I'm assuming you're aware that's unfinished based on the fact you're also only checking `bank1` to see if the client has an account there - any other bank will just fire an update aimed at nothing, making the transferred amount disappear or pop up out of nowhere. See the balances before and after your EoD transfers: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IHIkLpU9).

---

If you want different banks to have some additional columns, you can use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html). If you want to keep your current tables and also merge them and be able to interface with all as one, with automated routing of records to/from their corresponding bank's table based on the `bank_id`, you can set up a [partitioned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) table and attach them as partitions. It will be still possible to interface with individual tables directly as well as with all of them at once, through the common name.